# Can't make new folder in AWS EC2

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to make a new folder to SCP my python script so i can run it on AWS EC2 instance.

So I have SSH and connected to my instance. I tried `ls` nothing shows.

`pwd` shows:

```
/home/ec2-user
```

`mkdir /newFile` shows:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/newFile': Permission denied
```

`sudo mkdir /newFile` shows no error. 
But when I `ls`, nothing shows. 
What is happening?

**I am using a macbook, and my instance is AWS Linux AMI.**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in the `/home/ec2-user` directory but you are creating a folder in the root `/` of your filesystem. If you want to make a subdirectory in your current directory do this:

```
mkdir newFile
```

Leave off your prefixed `/`

Comment: God, can't believe I'm so dumb. Might you, by any chance have a link to a cheat sheet of such commands?

Comment: Dont be so hard on yourself. Everyone starts somewhere. I dont have any great cheatsheets but this page seems to cover a lot of commands by category https://www.linuxtrainingacademy.com/linux-commands-cheat-sheet/